# WebRequest to post data in Login page

Tags: c#, http-post

I read questions with similar titles and test codes but my problem is not solved.
My problem: I need a program in C# that post dates to a modem login page. My modem is wimax bm632. The address of login page is htp://192.168.1.1/ and the action of form that there is 
in http://192.168.1.1/ is http://192.168.1.1/index/login.cgi (form action). I want when login is success then go to http://192.168.1.1/html/wimax/security.asp and get page source.
login page : http://chamalz.persiangig.com/image/1.JPG

I write this code:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.1.1/index/login.cgi");

        request.Method = "POST";

        string postData = "Username=admin&Password=YWRtaW4%3D";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);

        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();

        dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        dataStream.Close ();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();

        textBox1.Text=(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusD  escription);

        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);

        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();

        textBox1.Text= (responseFromServer);

        reader.Close ();
        dataStream.Close ();
        response.Close ();
```

This code has no error but have a problem : when I post my user name and password correct or incorrect I received one response in textBox1.Text
the response is : http://chamalz.persiangig.com/image/2.JPG

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to know what data are sent to login page via POST Method.
for achieving this you must login manualy and capture posted data to login page
this possible by using http capture software like httpdebugger
after you find correct post data and httpheader you can put data on your code and try login programaticaly

Comment: Host: 192.168.1.1

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Connection: keep-alive

Referer: http://2.146.200.26/

Cookie: FirstMenu=Admin_0; SecondMenu=Admin_0_0; ThirdMenu=Admin_0_0_0; Language=en; SessionID_R3=526578199

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Content-Length: 34



post content:

Username=admin&Password=YWRtaW4%3D

Comment: you need to set cookie for request,first u must read login page response and get Set-Cookie header from login page then  you must set cookie like your captured request